# Define a method in interface with different parameters (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to define two methods with different parameters but same names . Is it possible?

Suppose I have two classes, the first for hourly employees and second for commissioned employees and one method in the interface:

```
 GetSalaryInformation()
```

I want to define two methods like this 
for hourly employees

```
 GetSalaryInformation(int hourToWork)
```

and for commissioned employees

```
 GetSalaryInformation(float howmuchSold)
```

Comment: What happens when you write those few lines in your IDE instead of here? Does it compile and work? Yes, it's possible. (But when calling the `float` version, you might need to be explicit like `GetSalaryInformation(3f)` to help the compiler infer the correct method). And it may even be better to give different - speaking - names like `GetHourlySalaryInformation` and `GetPercentageSalaryInformation`.

Comment: That is absolutely possible by polymorphism.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee And moreover you cannot change the signature of an interface method in an implementor. That way lies madness. This question *looks* like overloading but I'm almost sure it is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** you cannot do this; at least not the way you are thinking.

Implementors of an interface may not change the signature of methods on the interface (they can, of course, add their own).

So this code is **not** valid:

```
interface IEmployee
{
    void PayMe()
}

class Salaried : IEmployee 
{
    void PayMe(int salary) { }
}

class Hourly : IEmployee
{
    void PayMe(int rate, int hours) { }
}
```

Both derived classes *must* have `PayMe` with no parameters. This is super important; if the parameters keep changing you can't call the method with an `IEmployee` reference (how do you know what parameters to pass???).

Now; each derived class could implement the no param PayMe *in addition to* their own parameterized version but at that point you aren't going through the interface so... why are you bothering with the interface exactly?

Comment: So I can't use this way . Can i define two methods in interface(with same name ) and implement just one method in my class ?

Comment: @amirmehr: What do you think will happen?  **Now try it and see what happens**.

Answer (score 3):

You want interfaces to be substitutable.  Your desires are accurate, but your implementation isn't type safe.  You can rework your interface to simply be substitutable and get that polymorphism that you are chasing:

```
void Main()
{
    var emp = new CommissionedEmployee();
    emp.ProductsSold = 100;
    var emp2 = new SalariedEmployee();
    emp2.HoursWorked = 160;

    var employees = new List<IEmployee> {emp, emp2};
    foreach (var e in employees)
    {
        e.GetSalaryInformation();
    }

}

interface IEmployee
{
    void GetSalaryInformation();
}

class SalariedEmployee : IEmployee
{
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
    private int someFixedRateIMadeupForDemo = 15;


    public void GetSalaryInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Salary: {HoursWorked * someFixedRateIMadeupForDemo}");
    }
}

class CommissionedEmployee : IEmployee
{
    public float ProductsSold {get;set; }
    private int someFixedRateIMadeupForDemo = 25;
    public void GetSalaryInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Salary: {ProductsSold * someFixedRateIMadeupForDemo}");
    }
}
```

This is a contrived example, but hopefully you get the basic idea.  You can dig into "Liskov Substitution Principle" if you want to get really deep into this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can solve your problem with extension methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var salaried = new Salaried();
    var hourly = new Hourly();
    salaried.PayMe(100);
    hourly.PayMe(100, 8);
}

class Salaried { }
class Hourly { }

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void PayMe(this Salaried salaried, int salary)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public static void PayMe(this Hourly hourly, int salary, int hours)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```